# How to check if an URL is already cached with $http.get() in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, caching

According to this question, i just have to set `{cache: true}` in `$http.get()`. My question is how do I check if an URL is already cache when I perform `$http.get()`?

Answer (score 2):

When using $http.get() with {cache: true} option, it will automatically cache http GET requests using angular's built in $cacheFactory.

Assuming you're using the default configuration for caching, those are cached in a cache object with the name '$http'.
To access the cache object in your controller, you'll need to inject the $cacheFactory service and access it like this:

```
angular.module('cacheExampleApp', []).
    controller('CacheController', ['$scope', '$cacheFactory', '$log', function($scope, $cacheFactory, $log) {
        var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
        var httpCacheObj = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
        var urlCache = httpCacheObj.get(url)
        if (urlCache && urlCache[1]) {
            $log.debug('request already cached.');
        } else {
            $log.debug('request is not cached.');
        }
        $http.get(url, {cache: true}).then(function(response){
            // do something with the response...
        });
    };
}]);
```

Some notes:

- Angular will not make an http request if a request is already cached, but the mechanism is still the same (using $http.get().then() to access it).
- $cacheFactory.get('$http') is the default cache object for cached $http.get() requests.
- The url for each requests is the key stored in the cache object.
- When accessing a key in the cache object an Array is returned. I did not find documentation for it, but seems like each key in the array can contain 4 values if already cached:

  - `urlCache[0]` -> the response code (for example 200)
  - `urlCache[1]` -> the response body as string. If the response is in json format, it can be converted back to a JSON object by using `JSON.parse(urlCache[1]);`
  - `urlCache[2]` -> An object holding a key-value list of headers and their values.
  - `urlCache[3]` -> a String representing the meaning of the response code (for example 'OK' status 200).

see [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2959/)